# Modal not picking up correct values

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am just wondering why this modal isn't picking up the correct values. When I click on the button it will only display one value's additional information. I read somewhere it maybe due to some id thing but can't figure it out.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I think you're correct, `data-target="#breedModal"` should be unique if you have many modals, you could maybe append the breed id (if it exists) on to the the id attribute of the modal within each iteration. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There you go, hope that makes more sense, edited to provide a working solution within django.

Comment: you should not edit your question after it has been answered, it removes the value for future users. Also think the selected answer is poor in quality as does little to explain the issue that you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your code as follows

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#breedModal">Click Here</button></td>
```

to

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#breedModal_{{forloop.counter}}">Click Here</button></td>
```

and

```
<div class="modal fade" id="breedModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="breedModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

to

```
<div class="modal fade" id="breedModal_{{forloop.counter}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="breedModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Now, I will generate unique model id's for each row.

Answer (score 0):

In essence what I am saying is that you have:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="breedModal" ...
```

But you're creating this multiple times within the iteration (for loop). You need to have the id unique so I suggested something more like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="breedModal{{ breed.id }}" ...
```

Anyways, you'd need to change the reference to this aswell:

```
<button type="button" data-target="#breedModal{{ breed.id }}"...
```

That way you have a unique id for each modal so when you click the button it knows which of the many modals it should open.

Currently all of the buttons say open `#breedModal` but because there are many of them you are only seeing the first one.

EDIT:

In reality though you don't have the `breed.id` value in your database so use a key value pair in your for iteration, see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for.

So then you have:

```
{% for key, breed in breeds %}
```

Then instead of trying to use `breed.id` as I suggested just use `key` (is going to be a numeric key relating to the record index) so your id attribute will render as `breedModal0`, `breedModal1`, etc.